# Converting large (4gb) avi file to mpeg or mp4 format using C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I have successfully converted avi files to Mpeg using NREco converter http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx

But, the length (duration) of the converted video is never greater than 2mins, 35 secs.
I tried using ffmpeg command line utility (https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html or http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ ffmpeg 64 bit static for windows) but the length was always less than or equal to 2mins, 35 seconds. 
How to increase the duration of the ffmpeg converted video?

I tried the -t command but couldn't increase the length (duration) of the converted video. Original video is a 14mins 5 sec avi file.

```
ffmpeg -i inputAVIfilename outputMPEGfilename
ffmpeg -i inputAVIfilename -t 90000 outputMPEGfilename
```

The video file has only bitmap images. No sound tracks are required.

Please note that my dll would be used with both windows & web applications.

Comment: FFMpeg has no any internal limitations for video length and can be used for converting huge video files (like films). It's hard to advise anything because of lack of details about your particular situation. At least you can provide command line you've used for converting your avi files; maybe they are encoded incorrectly and 2:35 that's all FFMpeg can decode?

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko Can NReco.VideoConverter be used with an ASP.NET MVC application?

Answer (score 0):

Converting of videos of from one format to other can be done either using software or hardware. In your case you are using ffmpeg which is software based solution. Generally speaking software based solutions are a lot slower, inefficient and has many operating system restrain, and I am suspecting you have reached that limit.

I suggest that you use cloud based solution such as Azure Media service or Elementals.